# Batch mxd processing returns AssertionError: Invalid mxd filename?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I have a number of .mxd files in a folder, in which i need to run certain operations. On one of them, specifically, when I try assigning it to a variable, I keep getting this error (and it's not the first of the lot):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 611, in __init__
    assert (os.path.isfile(mxd) or (mxd.lower() == "current")), gp.getIDMessage(89004, "Invalid MXD filename")
AssertionError: Invalid MXD filename.
```

However, I'm pretty sure the name of the file is correct, and I can normally open it in ArcMap. Would anyone know what could be causing it? Here is the code I've been using to do it (fully functional for the others...):

```
import arcpy
import os
from os.path import join
mxdPath = "C://1331/DB/Original Files/MXD/"
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(mxdPath):
        for f in filenames:
        mxd_path = os.path.join(root, f)
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path) #This line returns the error for one specific file

        #Some processing on the file: changing references, saving it as new file, etc;
        del mxd
```

If it helps, the problematic file is called: "Figura 2.11 - Áreas Prioritárias.mxd". I've tried changing its name (other files have spaces and special characters, but the code runs without an issue for them), but it didn't help either.
All the other files in the folder were made by the same person and in the same version of ArcGis, and are named alike. Eg: "Figura 2.10 - Unidades de Conservação", "Figura 2.13 - Densidade Demográfica", etc. The code works for these without an issue.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Can you give some examples of other filenames that contain spaces and/or special characters?  Are they the same special characters?  Please [edit] your question to include this additional info.

Comment: If you copy your file to something like C:\temp\test.mxd does the same code work on that?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Copying it to "C://temp/" and erasing all special characters and spaces did the trick. I would like to do it with the original names, but it's not a big issue. I still don't understand though why it works for some, but not for all (length of the full filepath is not the problem either, since this is not the largest).

Comment: If you run `os.path.isfile(mxd_path)` does it return True or False?

Comment: You need the "raw" modifier on string constants with path backslashes.  Creating files with spaces in their names is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: You could potentially rename/copy the file first, process your mxd, and then rename/copy it back to keep the filename.  That said I think removing spaces and special characters is preferred when using python.

Comment: @Paul, running `os.path.isfile(mxd_path)` returns False if the path was set at runtime. I tried setting the path (by copying the address and pasting it specifically for this one) and it returns True in this situation.

Comment: @Vince, thanks for the input. I tried switching it for the raw modifier with backslashes but the problem persisted.

Comment: @Midavalo, Thanks, I'll give it a try. I really can't control all the mxd filenames, since they are 3rd party, and there are just too many (and too often) to be consistently renamed. It would seem this suggestion could avoid this kind of problem in the future.

Comment: If it's returning `False` at runtime, then the path is being built incorrectly.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but printing the mxd_path returns the exact filename (perhaps it understood one of the special characters differently?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your `mxdPath` as `unicode` by adding a `u` before the string

```
mxdPath = u"C:\\1331\\DB\\Original Files\\MXD"
```

Also leave out the trailing slash `\` as it's not needed for `os.path.join()` to work, and has the potential to cause issues.

```
import arcpy, os

mxdPath = u"C:\\1331\\DB\\Original Files\\MXD"
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(mxdPath):
        for f in filenames:
        mxd_path = os.path.join(root, f)
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path) #This line returns the error for one specific file

        #Some processing on the file: changing references, saving it as new file, etc;
        del mxd
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `r` before the path to indicate `raw`  may solve the problem:

```
mxdPath = r"C://1331/DB/Original Files/MXD/"
```

Maybe even remove your extra `/`:

```
mxdPath = r"C:/1331/DB/Original Files/MXD"
```

Or do what [ERSI suggests](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/supplement/pathnames-explained-absolute-relative-unc-and-url.htm). `raw` format and single backslash `\`:

```
mxdPath = r"C:\1331\DB\Original Files\MXD"
```